# Is it valid to Html-Encode a URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss, html-encode

I have the following snippet in my view:

```
<div id="recommendFooter">
    <% string urlRecommend = Url.Action("RecommendProduct", "Products", new { url = ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString() }); %>
    <div>
        <a href="<%= urlRecommend %>">This product is awesome!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should output  Html like this:

```
<div id="recommendFooter">
     <div>
        <a href="http://www.mysite.com/Products/RecommendProduct?url=http://www.mysite.com/products/productbykey/20" >This product is awesome!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not shure if I can Html-Encode urlRecommend or even the value ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString().

I have Request - Validation enabled , but for this part lets assume I dont have it enabled. Can and should I Html-Encode here?

**EDIT 1**

I suppose this is what Guffa suggests:

```
  <div id="recommendFooter">
        <% string urlRecommend = Url.Action("RecommendProduct", "Products",  new { url = Server.UrlEncode( ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString() )}); 
string urlRecommendXssSave = Server.HtmlEncode(urlRecommend );

%>
        <div>
            <a href="<%= urlRecommendXssSave %>">This product is awesome!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value should be HTML encoded as it's in an attribute in the HTML code, but that doesn't make any difference here as there are no characters that need escaping.

What you need to do is to URL encode the value in the query string in the URL.

The HTML code for the link should end up like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/Products/RecommendProduct?url=http%3a%2f%2fhttp%3a%2f%2fwww.mysite.com%2fproducts%2fproductbykey%2f20">This product is awesome!</a>
```

(Note: I preserved the duplicate `http://` in the value from your question, you should probably fix that also.)

Comment: You wrote that I dont need to HTML-Encode because there are no characters that need escaping. Suppose there would be those characters: would I use the logik in my edit?

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner: Yes, that would be correct. You can also use the `<%: %>` tag to HTML encode the string.